# The push & reveal type of ion-menu does not work

Tags: ionic-framework

I've been trying the ion-menu of Ionic 3. The "type=overlay" function works properly as the side menu overlays the screen, yet neither "push" nor "reveal" values for "type" attribute seem to be working.

When I click the button, nothing happens, but the button is sure clicked as I've checked. I have not tried them in an emulator/phone if they work. But [the ionic-documents on it](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/menu) shows it can be tested on browser.

```
<ion-menu side="start" menuId="first" [content]="content" type="push">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="primary">
      <ion-title>Start Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content #content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
      <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button menuToggle (click)="openFirst()"><ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon></button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content>
  content
</ion-content>
```

.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    private menu: MenuController) {

  }

  openFirst() {
    this.menu.enable(true, 'first');
    this.menu.open('first');
  }
}
```

I expect this code the push the entire page and reveal the side bar menu, but it does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Button click function is not required as menuToggle is used :

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
     <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
     <ion-buttons end>
       <button ion-button menuToggle ><ion-icon name="add"> 
         </ion-icon></button>
     </ion-buttons>
 </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Also check this link. 
I have implemented menu type.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4j3yqp?file=app/app.html

Comment: I know realize I PUT THE #content tag in wrong place. I should have put the #content to the content which I want to see pushed side. Instead I put it on the ion-menu's content which it didn't work. After I put #content in page's own content it worked. Thanks.